# PHP code and html are not rendering in webpages

Tags: html, web

Recently i can't render pages in php and html. it is all junk codes like this
![screenshot taken when page loads][1]

Is there any setting in php to render actual content?

BELOW is the content i see when i access pages in browser.

"
 ��\�s۶����+P�S%sm������$��7n}j�����p( �S$ˇm����~�_�D:��6��I`,>,v��G߼����׋Wb-q����7g�v�l��{�l��z)���W�oE���Q`[Q������^mE��f����q�mx��y�K���iS9�xr��4��N���������*h��cU�&�vp\s��&ӝפ��{GiN�w�(�#G�\z�m:�'�z����ř�\Ʈ�ġ��ne ���J���ww�T������L��Ky\3�h��)�s#�F�5E^Mn�)�����ؾ9��)�ë�/s�"y5��υ�0�PF���^� ���� O�\�P��M����T�V`��������R ۝y�Ҥ,aN�8+/DhG��hl�+�&^�g�v���`�9�w[��w�^�sy�31������i-�!AxN�k�;䬭��o2��a{+����YR�c��"��q-�XG��TMD����yw��������Ĝ�a���͙yC$ �$��!���|0oL�JB��wc�;�)�şu ;4���v-��L�L'�B��ҢA4��4v$r9��l?�f��e�P�~�U�x���&�y�ҥ���x0��Ӯ9�ڽN�?������ ".

Comment: what!!...........? Can u re-edit your question ?

Comment: @Testerdeveloper - whatever it is you are testing send it back it may need a tweak or two. This will break internet. ;) Make sure your files have same caracter encoding as webserver, ditto for database if the page has dynamic all must use the same encoding. UTF-8 is pretty much what people go where I am from.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it's an Apache (or whatever webserver you're using) configuration problem.  It looks like php files are being processed by something other than PHP.  Check your MIME type handler for .php files in **httpd.conf**.

Comment: how in god's name did you understand the question? All I am seeing are  a lot of non-printabel characters.

Comment: Unfortunately I've seen this kind of thing before :)

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Yes, I see unprintable characters too.  That's what the poster is complaining about

Comment: Unpritable characters are something i see when i access web page..that is the question i asked why it was like this?